# Find in which order original elements were removed from an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with the following task:

At the beginning you start with an array of n numbers from 1 to n. Then you remove entries one by one by choosing the index in the current array.
I am to output the order in which the original elements were removed.

For example:

Input:

```
6

1 4 4 2 2 1
```

Output:

```
1 5 6 3 4 2
```

Speed is important, so I need the solution to be as fast as possible. It seems it can be done in little-oh(n^2) but I don't know how. The solution has to be C++.

My correct, albeit too slow solution:

```
int n = 0;
std::cin >> n;

std::vector<int> nums(n);
std::iota(nums.begin(), nums.end());

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int toRemove;
    std::cin >> toRemove;
    --toRemove;
    std::cout << nums[toRemove] << " ";
    nums.erase(nums.begin() + toRemove);
}
```

Comment: At least give it a try and when you face problem if you ask it would be more appreciable, here you just typed out your homework directly to stackoverflow.

Comment: I did try and found a correct solution, albeit too slow. I didn't type it as I didn't want the post to get too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your container type from a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to a [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) then you can avoid having to copy the elements every time you remove one. This should be much more efficient, however the increased complexity of the lookup bogs down this solution too much to be an improvement except in a nearly optimal case.

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container>
class LookupRemove {
  typedef Container<T, std::allocator<T> > ContainerType;
public:
  LookupRemove(int size): 
  remaining(size),
  nums(size) {
    std::iota(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 1);
  }

  T removePosition(T position) {
    if (position < remaining) {    // make sure advance doesn't go past end
      auto pos = nums.begin();
      std::advance(pos, position); // set the position to retrieve and remove
      T value = *pos;
      nums.erase(pos);
      --remaining;
      return value;
    }
    return 0;
  }
private:
  ContainerType nums;
  T remaining;
};

int main() {
  int n = 1000000;

  LookupRemove<int, std::vector> lookupVector(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    lookupVector.removePosition(0);
  }

  LookupRemove<int, std::list> lookupList(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    lookupList.removePosition(0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Some time profiling measurements:

```
elements:   10000
vector:       5.0 ms
list:           - ms

elements:  100000
vector:     639.0 ms
list:         1.0 ms

elements: 1000000
vector:   83022.0 ms
list:        25.0 ms
```

edit: This profiling is flawed because it's the optimal case for removing from a list, removing the first member every time. Profiling with random positions shows comparable times removing from a vector vs removing from a list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this optimization doesn't help me. Removing elements is quicker, yes, but finding element is much longer (O(n) instead of O(1)). As I look for an element on each iteration of the loop this code is still O(n^2) and (at least on my computer) it doesn't run significantly faster.

Comment: @Narimax I did some profiling and it looks like you're correct, switching from a vector to a list as I have here doesn't improve the time complexity of the function.